# I need to alphabitize my CD's and am confusing myself by also trying to go by genre

Tags: music

I've bought 2 soft cases to put my 500 or so CD's which hold 400 each.  Is there a program that allows me to speak, rather than type the information to sort them alphabetically?

Comment: What platform? macOS can do speech to text natively.

Comment: Yes. On windows, look into JAVT application on window. Not only can it rename file.